# How test async/await code used in LocationManager

Tags: swift, unit-testing, async-await

I dont know how to write a test to check if array is populated with appropriate values.

To save you time I'll shorten my code

Array to be populated and protocol

```
   var forecast :[ForecastDay] = []

 var session : URLSessionProtocol = URLSession.shared
  
      protocol URLSessionProtocol{
func data(from url: URL, delegate: URLSessionTaskDelegate?  ) async throws -> (Data, URLResponse)
 }

  extension URLSession: URLSessionProtocol{}
```

The first is where func is called from when app starts:

```
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])  {
    if !locations.isEmpty,currentLocation == nil{
        currentLocation = locations.first
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
        Task{
            await requestWeatherData()
        }
    }
}

   func requestWeatherData() async {
    
    guard let currentLocation = currentLocation else {return}
    let longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude
    let latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude
    let long = longitude.description
    let lat = latitude.description
    
    let data = await fetchForecastForMyLocation(lat, long)
    switch data{
    case .success(let info):
        self.forecast = info
      ...
     //
     ...
  
    func fetchForecastForMyLocation(_ lat: String, _ long: String) async -> Result<[ForecastDay],MyError>{

let urlString : = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=\(lat!)&lon=\(long!)&units=metric&appid=6f82f48c92e97ee65b96d117f86d4e0d"


let url = URL(string: urlString)!
var decodedData : [ForecastDay] = []
do{
    let (data, response) = try await session.data(from: url, delegate: nil)
    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,response.statusCode == 200 else{
        return .failure(MyError.noDataAvailable)
    }
    
    if let decodedJSON = try?
        
        JSONDecoder().decode(ForecastResponse.self,from: data){
```

This is how I made mock because I don't want to use OOHTTPStubs

```
class MockURLSession: URLSessionProtocol{
var result = Result<Data,Error>.success(Data())

func data(from url: URL, delegate: URLSessionTaskDelegate?) async throws -> (Data, URLResponse) {
    try(result.get(),URLResponse())
    }
}
```

I also added this func for json data in tests

```
   private func jsonData() -> Data {
    """
  {
    "weekDay" : "Monday",
    "hourForecast": [
      {
        
        "minTemp": 2.0,
       "maxTemp":3.0,
     "icon": "stain",
    "time": "11h",
     "name" : "NewYork",
     "temp" : 3.0,
      "description": "lol",
     "wind" : 3.0,
     "date" : "lol",
     "simpleDescription": "idegas"     
  }       
      ]
      
  }
""".data(using: .utf8)!
    
}
```

Comment: It's good that you shortened your code. Can you give enough to at least make it compile though?

Answer (score 1):

The point here is to make your logic testable. The easiest way to do that is to move your logic into separate functions. That way you won't *need* to make a mock. To that end:

```
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
final class Example {
    var session: URLSession!

    func fetchForecastForMyLocation(_ lat: String, _ long: String) async -> Result<[ForecastDay], Error> {
        await convertToResult {
            let url = ForecastEndpoint.url(lat: lat, long: long)
            let (data, response) = try await session.data(from: url, delegate: nil)
            return try ForecastEndpoint.parse(data: data, response: response)
        }
    }
}

func convertToResult<A>(_ fn: () async throws -> A) async -> Result<A, Error> {
    do {
        return try .success(await fn())
    }
    catch {
        return .failure(error)
    }
}

struct ForecastEndpoint {
    static func url(lat: String, long: String) -> URL {
        let urlString = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=\(lat)&lon=\(long)&units=metric&appid=6f82f48c92e97ee65b96d117f86d4e0d"
        return URL(string: urlString)!
    }

    static func parse(data: Data, response: URLResponse) throws -> [ForecastDay] {
        guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, response.statusCode == 200 else {
            throw MyError.noDataAvailable
        }
        let decodedJSON = try JSONDecoder().decode(ForecastResponse.self, from: data)
        var forcastDays = [ForecastDay]()
        // extract days from decodedJSON
        return forcastDays
    }
}
```

Now you can test that `ForecastEndpoint.url(_:_:)` and `ForecastEndpoint.parse(data:response:)` work correctly without having to mock anything. And `fetchForecastForMyLocation(_:_:)` is just effects. There's nothing in there to test (we don't unit test effects.)

A couple of videos explaining the idea:

- [Boundries](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/talks/boundaries)
- [Test Doubles are a Scam - Matt Diephouse](https://youtu.be/7AGQ9dhWCX0)
- [Clean Architecture in Python - Brandon Rhodes](https://youtu.be/DJtef410XaM)

(Yes, the second video is in Python, but the architecture ideas are still relevant.)

Comment: "fetchForecastForMyLocation(_:_:) is just effects. There's nothing in there to test" I don't agree with that at all. It is testable and it should be tested.

Comment: @matt I guess you could test to ensure that if `data(from:delegate:)` or `parse(data:response:)` throws an error, that the error is converted to a `.failure` result... Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: In part, sure. There's logic here. There's given input and expected output. It needs testing.

Comment: When you say "testing" are you talking *unit* tests? As in removing effects? Or integration tests? I was only thinking about unit testing here...

Comment: It's not a semantic question. Coordinates in, Result out; that needs testing.

Comment: Okay...I don't know how to think about this, I  really liked DanielT. possible solution it was new way of thinking for me and it's a lot easier to do tests now with that idea in my head. @matt can I provide you more information for your solution if you would like to post it?

Comment: I added another video to the answer... When you are mocking out effects. The thing to watch out for is that you aren't just testing the mock. This means that you need to assert that the input into the mock is the correct value and that the code that uses the mock's output produces the correct output... In other words, you want to test the code just before and just after the part that was mocked, not the mock itself. So move that code out where it can be tested without mocking.

Comment: I have updated my answer to move the `do { } catch { }` logic out of the `fetchForecastForMyLocation(_:_:)` function. There is no logic left to test in there now...

Comment: But you don't really need to mock anything in order to test code involving a network download. The ability to inject a pseudo download, so as not to touch the real network, is built in. It seems to me that explaining about that should be part of the answer here. Saying "there's something here that doesn't need test coverage" seems wrong to me.

Comment: Good point, but they said they didn't want to use OHHTTPStubs. I took that to mean that they didn't want to inject a pseudo download. Now I grant that there are other ways you could inject a pseudo download, but that's how I interpreted it...

Comment: I interpreted it as "I'm unaware that there is a far better way than OHHTTPStubs, a way that is easy, native, and official." You have to mock the network _somehow_; otherwise you end up with "oh well, this doesn't really need testing" which I think is fallacious, as I've said several times now.

Comment: URLProtocol...I just figure it out. @matt

Comment: Yep, that's my point.

Comment: My question may be very bad but Im glad I asked and figure out what were you talking about. Thanks both matt and Daniel.